# Use the pick rendition in a Multiple Lines of text field?

Tags: 2013, image, image-rendition

We created a custom list "news" and created a Multiple lines of text field column named "Content" with a specified type: enhanced rich text.[image]

We are able to insert images but can’t use the pick rendition button.
[image]

On a wiki page I’m able to use the pick rendition, so everything seems correctly configured to use the pick rendition. Does anyone have an idea how to use the pick rendition in a custom list, Multiple Lines of text field?